# How to copy inner list to a new list

Tags: c#, list, linq, arraylist, copy

I have a list that got nested lists and I would like to copy one list to a new list so that I can use it. I can get the list I want by specifying the index but I can't get to copy it to the new list that I want to use. I am just not too sure what would be the best way of doing this.

How can I copy the inner list to a new list so that I can use it as a plain list?

This is what I have tried.

```
    public bool myMethod(List<Summary> summaries)
    {
        var listIndex = summaries[1];
        List<newList> newLists = new List<newList>();

        //this didn't work as ToList is giving error
        List<newList> copy = listIndex.ToList(); //error: Summary does not contain a defination for ToList

        //I tried this too it didn't work
        var newCopy = indexer.Select(p => new newList
        {
          //my mapping
        }).ToList();

        return true;
    }
```

A model with all the list

```
public class Summary
{
    public IEnumerable<Model1> mylist1 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Model2> mylist2 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Model3> mylist3 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Model4> mylist4 { get; set; }
}
```

New list which I want to copy to

```
public class newList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    //more properties
}
```

Model1

```
public class Model2
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    //more properties
}
```

Comment: What does `model1` contain?

Comment: I have updated Model1 on the code.

Comment: you are accessing summaries with index but the type is `List<Summary>`?

Comment: Should I change it from IEnumerable to a list?

Comment: Why the index 1?  any specific reason? .. you could use `summaries.FirstOrDefault()` if u needed the first one.. else you can use the where condition to filter

Comment: Sorry, i made mistake i want Index two. I am not sure of how i can do it for index 2. Can you please show me how i can get my second list

Comment: `listIndex` is an object of type `Summary`. I think you probably meant to do something like `listIndex.mylist1.ToList();`.

Answer (score 0):

Here a working example of how you could do it:

---

```
    public void TestIt()
    {

        //Create list and add some test values
        Summary summary = new Summary();
        summary.myList = new List<B>()
        {
            new B(){Name = "name1", Surname = "surname1"},
            new B(){Name = "name2", Surname = "surname2"},
            new B(){Name = "name3", Surname = "surname3"},
        };

        List<Summary> mySummaries = new List<Summary>();
        mySummaries.Add(summary);
        CopyList(mySummaries);
    }

    private void CopyList(List<Summary> summaries)
    {
        var summary = summaries.FirstOrDefault();
        if (summary != null)
        {
            //Copy the list
            List<A> A = new List<A>(summary.myList.ConvertAll(x => (A)x));

            //Do what ever you want with the copied list...
        }

    }

    public class Summary
    {
        public List<B> myList { get; set; }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Surname;
    }

    public class B : A
    {

    }
```